# Java cannot find JavaFx classes although present in JDK

Tags: java, javafx, compiler-errors, javafx-9

I am currently working on an application using javafx for its UI. I am using java 9. When I pulled from github to continue development on my new computer and compiled, there were compilation errors at all references of javafx classes, and only javafx classes.

I searched in the jdk in external resources, and the javafx package was indeed where it was supposed to be. I also made a new project using the same jdk and opened a javafx window, which worked fine. This tells me that this is a project-specific issue, rather than a system issue.

Does anyone have some insight into this? Thanks.

EDIT
I am using Intellij comunity Ed. The error list was expansive, but here are a few
[image]

Comment: Did you (or your IDE) define a `module-info.java` file in your Java 9 project? What does the error say, exactly?

Comment: I updated the question with the error messages

Comment: So is there a `module-info.java` in the project?

Comment: Yes. quite a few actually

Comment: You will need `requires javafx.controls ;` in the `module-info.java` for the module using JavaFX. (You may need some other modules in addition.)

Comment: Which other ones?

Comment: It depends what you're using. The [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/overview-summary.html) organize packages by module, so you can see which packages are in which module (it's fairly intuitive anyway). If you require a module, you get its dependencies too (so requiring `javafx.controls` implicitly gets `javafx.graphics` and `javafx.base`, for example).

Comment: This worked with no compiler errors! Thanks. If you want, you can post a response and ill mark it correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your IDE may have set the project up as a "modular" Java 9 project. In modular projects, you specify which other modules the project depends on, and which packages in your module(s) should be exposed to other modules. A good general tutorial on modules is at the [OpenJDK wiki](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start).

If there's a `module-info.java` file in the classpath root, you need to explicitly state that your module requires access to the appropriate JavaFX modules. It may be enough just to add

```
requires javafx.controls ;
```

to this file: that will give you access to the [`javafx.controls` module](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx.controls-summary.html), and the modules on which it depends (`javafx.graphics` and `javafx.base`). Depending on your project, you may also need

```
requires javafx.fxml ;
```

and/or

```
requires javafx.web ;
```

etc.