# IntelliJ projects - not cross platform?

Tags: java, windows, macos, intellij-idea, javafx

Apologies if this question seems obvious. I have built an JAVAFX project in intellij on OSX. When I open this project up on a windows machine still in intellij, the compiler cant find any of the imported classes .

If I delete the imports and then alt-enter, intellij finds them straight away, yet still wont find them when compiling.

Is this due to the project being built with the OSX SDK and libraries?

```
Java FX\JavaFX-Events-
Continued-Source-code\src\sample\Main.java
Error:(3, 26) java: package javafx.application does not exist
Error:(4, 19) java: package javafx.fxml does not exist
Error:(5, 20) java: package javafx.scene does not exist
Error:(6, 20) java: package javafx.scene does not exist
Error:(7, 20) java: package javafx.stage does not exist
Error:(9, 27) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Application
Error:(12, 23) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Stage
  location: class sample.Main
Error:(11, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a                 supertype
Error:(13, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Parent
  location: class sample.Main
Error:(13, 39) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getClass()
  location: class sample.Main
Error:(13, 23) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable FXMLLoader
  location: class sample.Main
Error:(15, 35) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Scene
  location: class sample.Main
Error:(21, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method launch(java.lang.String[])
  location: class sample.Main
```

Comment: what build tool do you use?

Comment: I havnt really gotten in to the use of build tools so thats a hard question to answer, I want to say none as Im not building the application into any type of executable, im currently just testing it out and trying to run it within Intellij, so if intellij has a defualt or its own build tool, then that I guess...?

Comment: Try to look at IDEA's [Project Structure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-structure-dialog.html) dialog. It seems that you just need to set correct path to Java SDK on your new machine.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/q/48853477/2189127 and see if it is relevant

Comment: In turns out this is to do with the Modules element of Java 9, I just rolled back to Java sdk 8 and it worked fine.